# Is It Possible to Round a Number Smaller Than 1 In SQL While Keeping In Decimal Form

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I am not finding the solution to this issue despite looking specifically for it.

The below query is me trying to get the last decimal places to appear properly.

```
select CAST(CAST(33 as float)/100 as decimal(5,3))
```

From here I am looking for how to round properly to .33 or if the result were .339 to round up to .34

What I am finding is that it will only round down to 0 because it is not a whole number.

Can someone point me in the right direction or if there is no good way let me know.

Comment: So you basically want to keep 2 decimals?

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2017, I am looking to keep 2 decimals and use the third to determine the direction that it is rounding.

Comment: There must be more to this question than you post. The code you did post returns a value of 0.33 - which appears to be exactly what you desire. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ccedbbead309151ee27092a1c59736fc) to demonstrate. If you are rounding in some fashion, what values are you providing to the round function?

Comment: From what I am seeing if the division came out to an answer of .339 then SQL would truncate to .33 what I am looking for is the best way to accurately round based on the 3rd digit.

I have not found a way to stop SQL from truncating rather than rounding even with the ROUND() function.

Comment: This query gives you the expected .339 `select CAST(CAST(339  as float)/1000 as decimal(5,3))`  So post your query that supposedly is rounding it down.

Comment: @SoumendraMishra: MSSQL *is* sql-server.

Comment: @GMB, sorry for the confusion. I was trying to say that, the tag was "sql" and changed to "sql-server" after my answer. As a result, my answer become invalid and end-up with negative votes. You can see my comments in the comment section of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your denominator isn't treated as an integer. You could tack on a `.0` or `CAST` or `CONVERT` it. In the case where you'd expect rounding down to occur:

```
SELECT 331 / 1000.0;
-- gives 0.331000

SELECT ROUND(331 / 1000.0, 2);
-- gives 0.330000

SELECT CAST(ROUND(331 / 1000.0, 2) AS DECIMAL(5, 2));
-- gives 0.33
```

In the case where you'd be expect rounding up to occur:

```
SELECT 339 / 1000.0;
-- gives 0.339000

SELECT ROUND(339 / 1000.0, 2);
-- gives 0.340000

SELECT CAST(ROUND(339 / 1000.0, 2) AS DECIMAL(5, 2));
-- gives 0.34
```

Note: you may not need to do both `ROUND` and `CAST` since I believe the rounding occurs implicitly, but it makes the intent more clear if you choose to write it as such.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this gets to the root of my issue.  I am just working to incorporate this knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**MySQL:**

```
select ROUND(339/1000,2)
0.34

select ROUND(33/100,2)
0.33
```

**SQL Server:**

```
select ROUND(339/1000.0,2)
0.340000

select ROUND(33/100.0,2)
0.330000
```

Comment: Your constants are interpreted as integers - and integer division will return zero. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b1c5447323f789f7214c3b4645f63f2e)

Comment: Executing these two as written will result in 0 for both.

Comment: No, this is 2 different examples with output and not intended to run in one-go !

Comment: @SoumendraMishra Understood, these two select statements (not the output) will each result in 0.

Comment: Ohh, my god. When the question was asked it was "sql", someone has added tag as "sql-server"

Comment: Added a new solution as question "tag" changed from "sql" to "sql-server"